# How to set width and height input with semantic-ui components

Tags: css, input, semantic-ui

Hello i am new in the semantic world and I want to customize the default input height and width I know that we have predefined classes in semantic like small, big, mini  but I need to have custom height and width.

In semantic documentation (http://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html) at the input section we have this message:

> "Inputs will automatically size themselves unless you manually declare
>   a width"

I have declared the width in the input like this:

```
<input  width="10" type="text" value="test" placeholder="empty" readonly>
```

but it doesn't work for me. A little help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Note: The width attribute is used only with `<input type="image">`.
>   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_width.asp

That's why your code doesn't work. To make it work, you can do this:

```
<input style="width:100px; height: 100px;" type="text" value="test" placeholder="empty" readonly>
```

Or use a CSS file:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You can change 100px to the width and height you want. Semantic UI won't set width and height for you, that's why they say **manually declare a width**.

Answer (score 2):

I tried successfully:

```
style={{minWidth:"10em"}}
```

for

```
<Form.Field width={3}><Select placeholder='Options' options={options} 
    style={{minWidth:"10em"}}/></Form.Field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set with for Semantic UI component using the style property.

It expects following syntax:

```
<Input style={{marginRight: spacing  'em'}}
```

In your example you should specify:

```
<Input style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would just put it in a custom css file

```
input[type="text"]{
height: 100px;
width: 400px;
}
```